# How to calculate standard deviation of a table in R?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I have a table of data that looks like this:

```
Category : Solution 1 : Solution 2 : Diff
1: 5 : 6 : -1
2: 7 : 6 : 1
3: 4 : 4 : 0
4: 8 : 9 : -1
```

How do I calculate the standard deviation within R?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean of the diff column? Then sd(.) on that column. If you want the whole table, I think you'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "standard deviation of a table"

Comment: Yes, of the difference, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sd(d$Diff)` should give you the standard deviation of that column

To get standard deviation of all columns

```
apply(d,2,sd)
```

Where `d` is the data frame.